# Advertencia al subir mi apk a la Consola del Google Play

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play-console

He agregado mi apk a la Consola y he obtenido el siguiente mensaje de advertencia:

> "...Tu uso de alarmas exactas está provocando que tu aplicación falle
> para algunos usuarios de Android Tu aplicación programa alarmas
> exactas sin comprobar si se te ha concedido el permiso
> SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM. Esto provoca que tu aplicación falle para los
> usuarios de Android 14 porque el permiso ya no se concede de forma
> predeterminada. En la mayoría de los casos, son más apropiados los
> métodos alternativos de programación de trabajo o las alarmas
> inexactas. Si tu uso de las alarmas exactas está justificado,
> actualiza tu aplicación para que compruebe que se te ha concedido este
> permiso antes de programar."

Desde la app no estamos utilizando en ningún momento ninguna alarma. Alguien sabe por qué me está dando esa advertencia?

En ninguna otra ocasión en la que hemos publicado actualizaciones de las app se nos ha solicitado permisos relacionados con alarmas puesto que no se utilizan.
Lo más extraño de todo es que cuando voy a resumen de la versión me sigue apareciendo como que está en revisión.
¿Cómo debo interpretar esta advertencia?
¿Debo esperar a que acabe la revisión o realmente no me dejarán publicar mientras esta advertencia siga ahí?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Con respecto al mensaje de advertencia que describes,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

puedes encontrar información en la documentación:

[Programa alarmas exactas rechazadas de forma predeterminada](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/changes/schedule-exact-alarms)

Si tu app se encuentra orientada con Android 13, deberías tener además del `SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM` el permiso `USE_EXACT_ALARM`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_EXACT_ALARM" />
```

pero si tu app se encuentra orientada con Android 14, además de definir los permisos que comento anteriormente, debes requerirlos manualmente

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
    val alarmManager = ContextCompat.getSystemService(context, AlarmManager::class.java)
    if (alarmManager?.canScheduleExactAlarms() == false) {
        Intent().also { intent ->
            intent.action = Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM
            context.startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Comentas que no usas alarmas ni tienes definido el permiso en `AndroidManifest.xml`, pero de acuerdo al análisis de Google Play debes definir el permiso ya que ahora para los usuarios de Android 14 el permiso `SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM` ya no se concede de forma predeterminada.**

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero es que mi app no utiliza alarmas ni tampoco tiene en el AndroidManifest ningún permiso relacionado con ellas. Aún así, la Consola de Google Play muestra ese warning.
Sospecho que pudiera tratarse de algún problema heredado de alguna Librería que sí necesitara utilizar esos permisos y que tenga explicitado en su propio código

Comment: De acuerdo al análisis de Google Play debes definir el permiso ya que ahora para los usuarios de Android 14 el permiso SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM ya no se concede de forma predeterminada."